# Models with almost same attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm trying to implement these things in my application but I'm not sure how to proceed and what ways is the best.

I would like to have different type of activities like restaurant, gym, store, ecc.
All these type of activities have the same 'base' attributes like name, city, address, email, but for example restaurant can also have 'food type' attribute or gym can have 'courses'.
I was thinking about not creating different models and so different tables that have redundant attribute, but creating a base model 'activity' and then models for 'store', 'gym', etc..

What is the best solution and how can i achieve it? I looked for STI and multiple inheritance table, but I'm not sure if they are suitable and which solution is the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but it does sound like you'd want to use relations, not inheritance.

A class (or model in the rails MVC paradigm) can have or belong to another model or models. That's called a relation. The models don't inherit from each other (although that is possible for other use cases.) They just have relationships between each other, the same way that database tables can have relationships between them. In fact, relations are how you declare the relationships between the underlying database tables for models.

Address is not the only model that has a relation to gym. A gym *is also* a business, so it `belongs_to` the business class. It *has* one and only one address so it `has_one` address.

You create models that each have their own attributes (attributes are created with a migration). How you set them up depends on your needs. Since your gym has to have an address, you create an Address model that contains the attributes for an address:

```
class Address
  # your attributes are in the database as created by your migration(s). You don't need to list them in the class.
  # validations, methods, etc.
end`
```

You then use your address model for anything that has an address. You don't need to repeat yourself by including address attributes in every class.

Then you set the relation between Gym and Address and Business in the model class.

Since your gym is a Business, (One of the many businesses in your global conglomerate :) you declare that it `belongs_to` the Business model.

A class can belong to more than one other class. A class can have one of another class or it have have many of another class. (There's also has_and_belongs_to_many, which is a bit more complicated.)

So here's your Gym model:

```
class Gym

  belongs_to :business

  has_one :address
  has_many :employees
  has_many :members
  #rest of Gym class

end
```

Now you can reference the the gym's address like this:

```
gym_one.address.line_1
gym_one.address.line_2
gym_one.address.ship_attention
gym_one.address.city
gym_one.address.state
gym_one.address.zip
gym_one.address.country
```

You can also reference which one of your businesses the gym belongs to:

```
gym_one.business
```

Assuming you set the relation between business and address you can get the address attributes for the gym's parent business:

```
gym_one.business.address.city
```

Now that you have a Gym class, you don't have to repeat your attributes in every class. You only add the attributes that are unique to a gym in your migration:

In db/migrations/{date_code}_create_gym:

```
class Gyms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gyms do |t|
      t.string :name
      # Other attributes that only a gym has. Not attributes of things that have a relation to Gym
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What if I add an 'item' model? Gym, store, restaurant, etc can create items. Is it correct to add in the model item 'belongs_to gym, belongs_to store, belongs_to restaurant, etc"?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to avoid 'store_id, gym_id, restaurant_id' in items table? Because for example, if a gym creates an item, then that entry in the database will have a 'gym_id' value but will have 'store_id' and 'restaurant_id' blank.

Comment: A store can have many items so you can add `has_many :items` to Store. Don't add `belongs_to :store` to Item because an Item isn't a store.

Comment: What if i want to keep track of which activity(bar,gym,store) an item belongs to?

Comment: You might want to search for "rails has and belongs to many". If you're using Rails 3+, skip anything for earlier versions. HABTM uses a join table to keep track of the many-to-many relation between stores and items. If you're not familiar with join tables (we all weren't at some point!), you might want to research how database relations work. Rails models give us an easy way to interact with the db relations "under the hood", but you still have to have an understanding of how database tables can relate to each other. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use relations here.

You can have model called Attribute, which has id and name. Then you create model called AttributeValue - which belongs_to attribute and restaurant, gym, store etc. Activities will have many attribute_values, and many attributes - through attribute_values.

Then you will have dynamic attributes - without duplicating data.

Combining this with STI and defined per model (restaurant, gym) constraints on attributes - checked using validations

Answer (score 0):

There is no general "best solution". Which concept suits best for your app is not that easy to determine. At least not without more concrete details about what you are planning.

Based on your examples of basic attributes, I would suggest to move them to their own model. city and address would make a location model, email (and probably other communication detail) might suit for a contact model or the like. These models can easily be referenced by different tables through polymorphic associations. That would leave only the name attribute to be present in all tables.

But this is just based on my understanding of your problem... There seem to be different interpretations about what you actually want to do.